# django organize compliance check

Tags: django

Please tell me if there is an opportunity to check the compliance of the finished product with the client's requirements. There are three models:

- manufacturers Manufacturer
- Car - the characteristics of the cars they make through a one-to-many
  connection.
- and customer model with their own requirements for color and engine
  power

I can't connect the customer with the Manufacturer and Car models. I would like to organize the check by type:

```
if self.color == self.client_color = True
    retur self.client_name
```

in other words, if the color matches the customer's color, then display the customer's name in the template

```
class Manufacturer(models.Model):
    # ...
    pass

class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey(Manufacturer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    engine_power = models.IntegerField()

    # ...
class Specification(models.Model):
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    client_color = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    client_engine_power = models.IntegerField()
```

maybe someone has already done this or similar

Comment: You should redesign your database first. With just a glance at your models one can find obvious issues. One of these issues is you use `unique=True` where it doesn't make much sense. A car must have a unique colour? A client would necessarily have a unique name?

Comment: i corrected this

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Your question is not very clear. Do you want all `Specification` instances whose `client_color` matches some given `Car` instances `color`?

Comment: yes. If the color and power of the machine match the client's specification, then the method returns true, I can't figure out how to access the attributes and properties of the specification model, should I use inheritance or something else?

Comment: Why not make a `Car` without a color, and then make a `ColorCar` that specifies the colors of that car. Then you can link the`Specification` to the `COlorCar`.

Comment: I don't know what you want to do you speak about some method returning something but give no context, anyway `Specification.objects.filter(client_color=color)` will give you all `Specification` instances where the colour is same as the variable colour.